# Merging or Simplifying 3 case statements to One

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I would to merge below 3 case statements to one and simplify as much as possible. Objective of query is to find out any member having invalid or valid phone number based on 3 columns. if any column having valid phone number then it is valid. if all are invalid then consider as invalid.Any help would be great.

```
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(DAY_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL) IS NULL
            THEN 1
  WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(DAY_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL) ='9999999999'
    THEN 1
        WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(DAY_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL))) = 10
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END INVALID_DAY_PH,
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(EVE_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL) IS NULL
            THEN 1
  WHEN  REGEXP_REPLACE(EVE_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL)='9999999999'
    THEN 1  
        WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(EVE_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL))) = 10
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END INVALID_EVE_PH,
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(MOB_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL) IS NULL
            THEN 1
   WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(MOB_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL)='9999999999'
    THEN 1  
        WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(MOB_PH, '[^[:digit:]'''']', NULL))) = 10
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END INVALID_MOB_PH,
```

Comment: Can you literally state in which cases a phone number is invalid?

Comment: Sure, 1). if 3 columns are blank then invalid.. 2).if 3 columns are having all 999999999 - 10 digits then invalid..1 and 2 can be clubbed like 2 columns are having blank and 3rd column having all 9’s then invalid..

Comment: Sample data showing all the permutations and the result you want might make this a bit clearer. Why do you have single quotes (twice) in your regex class; and why is 9999999999 a magic number?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify a bit just by pushing the regex calls into an inline view or CTE so you don't have to repeat them:

```
select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
  case when length(day_ph_cln) = 10 and day_ph_cln != '9999999999'
    then 0 else 1 end as invalid_day_ph,
  case when length(eve_ph_cln) = 10 and eve_ph_cln != '9999999999'
    then 0 else 1 end as invalid_eve_ph,
  case when length(mob_ph_cln) = 10 and mob_ph_cln != '9999999999'
    then 0 else 1 end as invalid_mob_ph
from (
  select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
    regexp_replace(day_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as day_ph_cln,
    regexp_replace(eve_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as eve_ph_cln,
    regexp_replace(mob_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as mob_ph_cln
  from your_table
);
```

The `trim()` doesn't seem to be doing anything so I've left that out - the regex will have removed any spaces already, as they aren't digits (or single quotes... I've left the pattern intact, though not sure it makes sense...)

If you want a single final flag to show if all the others were invalid then you can use `least()`, which will give you zero if any of the three other flags are zero, and 1 otherwise.

```
select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
  case when length(day_ph_cln) = 10 and day_ph_cln != '9999999999'
    then 0 else 1 end as invalid_day_ph,
  case when length(eve_ph_cln) = 10 and eve_ph_cln != '9999999999'
    then 0 else 1 end as invalid_eve_ph,
  case when length(mob_ph_cln) = 10 and mob_ph_cln != '9999999999'
    then 0 else 1 end as invalid_mob_ph,
  least(
    case when length(day_ph_cln) = 10 and day_ph_cln != '9999999999'
      then 0 else 1 end,
    case when length(eve_ph_cln) = 10 and eve_ph_cln != '9999999999'
      then 0 else 1 end,
    case when length(mob_ph_cln) = 10 and mob_ph_cln != '9999999999'
      then 0 else 1 end
  ) as all_invalid
from (
  select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
    regexp_replace(day_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as day_ph_cln,
    regexp_replace(eve_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as eve_ph_cln,
    regexp_replace(mob_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as mob_ph_cln
  from your_table
);
```

or use another level of subquery (or CTE) to remove the repetition:

```
select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
  invalid_day_ph, invalid_eve_ph, invalid_mob_ph,
  least(invalid_day_ph, invalid_eve_ph, invalid_mob_ph) as all_invalid
from (
  select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
    case when length(day_ph_cln) = 10 and day_ph_cln != '9999999999'
      then 0 else 1 end as invalid_day_ph,
    case when length(eve_ph_cln) = 10 and eve_ph_cln != '9999999999'
      then 0 else 1 end as invalid_eve_ph,
    case when length(mob_ph_cln) = 10 and mob_ph_cln != '9999999999'
      then 0 else 1 end as invalid_mob_ph
  from (
    select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
      regexp_replace(day_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as day_ph_cln,
      regexp_replace(eve_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as eve_ph_cln,
      regexp_replace(mob_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as mob_ph_cln
    from your_table
  )
);
```

If you **only** want that final flag then you can combine the case expressions:

```
select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
  case when (length(day_ph_cln) = 10 and day_ph_cln != '9999999999')
         or (length(eve_ph_cln) = 10 and eve_ph_cln != '9999999999')
         or (length(mob_ph_cln) = 10 and mob_ph_cln != '9999999999')
    then 0 else 1 end as all_invalid
from (
  select id, day_ph, eve_ph, mob_ph,
    regexp_replace(day_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as day_ph_cln,
    regexp_replace(eve_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as eve_ph_cln,
    regexp_replace(mob_ph, '[^[:digit:]'''']') as mob_ph_cln
  from your_table
);
```

You haven't supplied any sample data to verify that this gives the results you want; but [here's a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=94c34b55fe1c7ce0dd51a65e80c78fa4) with some very basic  made-up data.

Comment: Answer and examples are provided excellent, thanks for you're time on this, I'm not intended to use CTE or derive table. I would like to club all 3 phone numbers as one, means i need custom column - Y/N based on 3 phone numbers. if valid Y else N.

Comment: Using Y/N instead of 0/1 isn't an issue. (Might need greatest instead of least for some of the examples). I'm not sure why you don't want to use a CTE/inline view/derived table. Is this supposed to be an extra column in a result set, or a column on the actual base table? The same logic could be used for a virtual column.